# Yodlee Private Zone for Implementation & Testing REST API URL

Tags: yodlee

I have received the following credentials over the email for Private Zone for Implementation & Testing:

```
Cobrand Id,
Application Id,
Cobrand Username,
Cobrand Password,
SOAP Server URL.
```

it has only the SOAP Server URL, How do I get to know the REST Server URL.?

I have tried the coblogin via REST using the API given in the API reference 'https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/coblogin', but this doesn't give the session token, instead gives the following error

```
{
  "Error" : [
    {
      "errorDetail" : "Invalid Cobrand Credentials"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I know the rest API for my private zone.?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using is not applicable for your private zone. To get the REST URL for your cobrand please get in touch with the Yodlee engagement person with whom you have worked.

Comment: Oki, Thanks, I will talk to them and get the URL.